# Unable to access symbols published in VSTS Symbol server from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm able to successfully publish symbols to the VSTS symbol server as part of the build execution.

[image: Symbol publish log]

Followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/symbols/debug-with-symbols-visual-studio?view=vsts) to setup visual studio and everything good until this point. My symbol settings shown below:

[image]

When trying to debug, visual studio hits VSTS symbol server but return error message “Cannot find or open PDB file”

[image]

Below is the symbol load information provided by visual studio after trying to fetch from VSTS symbol server
[image]

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

As of November 15 2017 Visual Studio Online (also now known as Azure DevOps) the `Index Sources and Publish Symbols` build step handles the new portable PDB's create by `dotnet build`

You should tick `Publish symbols` and select your Subscription. The free tier has 5 users. You need to assign each user access to symbol server.

Ticking the `Index Sources` check box makes no sense though as the source files are on the build server, usually in an obscure location such as `C:\agent\_work\34\s\...` which will not match your local (or network path) to the source files.

To help Visual Studio find the source files you can do this... (you can avoid this by using SourceLink as described below)

- Select the solution in Solution Explorer and then choose Properties from the shortcut menu.
- Under the Common Properties node, choose Debug Source Files.
- Click the folder Tools/ Options/ Debugging/Symbols  folder icon icon. Editable text appears in the Directories containing source code list.
- Add the path that you want to search.

When you start debugging all the symbols will download and you can step into the source code now.

This does NOT require disabling just my code and you do not need to enable source server either.

---

Unless you are using, or would like to use source server. It is pretty easy to do now by adding a few packages...

With AzureDev ops you can modify your build pipeline to  make use of soruce files stored in GIT byt following this guide.

> The prerequisite is .NET Core SDK 2.1.300 or desktop msbuild version
>   15.7.

On your package project project you need to add NuGet package "SourceLink.Create.CommandLine" which will enable your build server (and your local build machine) to rewrite parts of the Portable PDB's without changing anything in the build pipeline.

You also need to add a package to the correct source control. [As described in this article.](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink) - I am using VSTS so I just install "Microsoft.SourceLink.Vsts.Git" package (must enable Include Prelease as of writing now)

To verify this works all you need to do is build the project and look inside `\obj\{config}\{tfm}\` for a file called `*.sourcelink.json` and has the correct URL's inside it.

Then the usual pack and publish you would do.

In Visual Studio you just need to enable

- Enable Source server support
- Enable Source Link support

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the application built in the **same build** as the build to publish symbols to VSTS Symbol server, the identity will be different in the different builds.

You can find that there is the GUID (**0CD368C47775439…**) in the Symbol load information, also you can check the Publish symbols task’s build log, there is the GUID too. Within a build the GUIDs will be the same and the symbols will be loaded correctly during debug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Source Server Support in the VS.NET debug options ?
You might also uncheck 'Enable Just My Code' in the VS.NET debug options.

There's a [blogpost](https://www.codit.eu/blog/2018/05/17/exposing-debug-symbols-using-vsts/) that I've recently written where I explain setting up and using a symbol server; might find some tips that might help you with your problem.

Comment: Please update your answer . The portable issue is not longer an issue. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/11/15/vsts-is-now-a-symbol-server/ explains this. The problem now is the source is linked to the build server path something like C:\agent_build\code\a\334\erc which is useless to me. What is the PDB for then. I can see it downloading all the PDB's when I start debug but stepping in says cannot find source file. I build everything using dotnet build -release - The documentation says the portable PDB is ALWAYS built and yes it is. But its no use really

Comment: I believe your pdb's are not indexed.  There's nothing in the article that you mention that makes me think that portable pdb's in .NET core are no longer an issue

Comment: Ahhhh.. damn sorry yes it was a paragraph here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/symbols/?view=vsts - Very subtle way of saying that it is now suppoerted. But yes I have it working now with portable PDB's I did not have to do all that stuff you said.I use `dotnet build` .  And I am actually experimenting with SourceLink back to VSTS GIT so it can just pull the correct source file automatically from GIT